# Node.js Twitter bot is posting multiple times despite using setInterval to post once per day

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, twitter

Here is the relevant code to my twitter bot. It is supposed to post 2 tweets, once per day. Something is making it post erratically. Sometimes it will send the two tweets twice, sometimes 3 times. The switch statements in the posting functions simply choose between a set of predefined statuses to post. When the bot posts multiple times, it has different statuses, so I know that somehow the posting functions are getting called multiple times because the random number is changing. The bot is hosted on heroku, if that helps. Does anyone know why it is posting multiple times?

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');
var config = require('./config');

var client = new Twitter(config);

const oneDay = 1000*60*60*24
var timeOfLastTweets = 0

// This is supposed to ensure that it only posts once per day.
start()
setInterval(start, oneDay)

function start() {
    var params = {
        screen_name: 'someScreenName', 
        include_rts: false, 
        count: 100
    }
    client.get('statuses/user_timeline', params, function(error, tweets, response) {
        if (!error) {
            var words = []
            for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {
                var time = new Date(tweets[i].created_at)
                if (isPast24(time))
                    // Splits words and removes punctuation in tweet and merges that array to the words array.
                    words = words.concat(tweets[i].text.replace(/[.,\/!\"$%\^&\*;:{}=_`~()]/g,"").split(' '))
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) { words[i] = words[i].toLowerCase() }
            tweetAnalysis(words)
        }
    });
}

// This function analyzes the words of tweets... the part relevant to the question is the last if statement.
function tweetAnalysis(words) {
    var wordCounts = {}
    var longestWord = ""

    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (words[i].includes('http') || words[i].length <= 4 || words[i].includes('@') || words[i].includes('#'))
            continue
        if (wordCounts[words[i]])
            wordCounts[words[i]] += 1
        else
            wordCounts[words[i]] = 1
        if (words[i].length > longestWord.length)
            longestWord = words[i]
    }

    var timesUsed = 1
    var mostUsed = ""
    for (key in wordCounts) {
        // If word has same frequency AND it's longer than the current mostUsed AND it's not also the longest word ^
        if (wordCounts[key] === timesUsed && key.length > mostUsed.length && key !== longestWord)
            mostUsed = key
        else if (wordCounts[key] > timesUsed) {
            timesUsed++
            mostUsed = key
        }
    }

    // Since it was posting multiple times, I made this so that the posting functions can't even be called until one day has passed, yet it still posts multiple times.
    var now = new Date()
    if (now >= timeOfLastTweets + oneDay) {
        timeOfLastTweets = now.getTime()
        //console.log(wordCounts)
        postMostUsed(mostUsed)
        postLongest(longestWord)
    }

}

// First posting function
function postMostUsed(word) {
    var status = ""
    switch (rnd(3)) { /* status gets a value */ }

    // Somehow each of these gets called twice.
    client.post('statuses/update', {status: status},  function(error, tweet, response) {
        if(error) throw error;
    });

    // console.log("Tweeting: " + status)

}

// Second posting function
function postLongest(word) {
    var status = ""
    switch (rnd(3)) { /* status gets a value */ }

    // Somehow each of these gets called twice.
    client.post('statuses/update', {status: status},  function(error, tweet, response) {
            if(error) throw error;
    });

    //console.log("Tweeting: " + status)

}

// Determines if the tweet was made in the past 24 hours.
function isPast24(date) {
    var ago24 = new Date()
    ago24 = ago24.setTime(ago24.getTime()-oneDay)
    var now = new Date()
    if (ago24 < date && date < now)
        return true
    else
        return false
}

function rnd(ceiling) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*ceiling)
}
```